# Azure DevOps Pipelines - force Stage to run on same instance in VMSS

Tags: azure-pipelines

Is there a way to force a Stage in Azure DevOps Pipelines to stay on the instance it started on in VMSS?

We noticed that some of the Jobs that execute pop up on different instances. The request from the powers that be is that we stay on the same VMSS for any given Stage (not Job). Unfortunately we are not permitted to refactor this to pull some of the steps we need executed into the Job.

I was reading [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/stages-stage?view=azure-pipelines) but was unable to find anything indicating that capability.

Comment: The powers that be need to understand that they've made a mistake in their request. All the tasks in one job automatically run on the same agent; but different jobs are independent, and cannot be constrained to run on the same agent.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The behavior you're seeing is intentional and by design -- each job is scheduled on an available agent instance when it starts running. This is to enable job-level parallelism and more efficiently consume your agent resources.

You can use demands to tell it to *always* run on the same agent instance, but in a VMSS scenario, that's not going to work as the agents are dynamically provisioned and deprovisioned. It can and will also cause bottlenecks because you're ignoring the fact that other agents exist, so you're effectively eliminating the benefits of having the VMSS able to auto-scale.

i.e.

```
pool:
  name: MyPool
  demands:
  - Agent.Name -equals agentinstance123
```

The bigger question is **why** this is a concern. I think this is an X/Y problem. i.e. "We're having problem X, we've decided the solution is Y. How do I do Y?", but "Y" is not a proper solution to problem X. Tell us what problem X is.

Comment: I agree with the X/Y problem, but it's not under my control. I really, really don't like it but it's the limitations we were put under. We are actually doing a POC on GitLab for them right now anyway, so this may completely go away in a bit.